# Run jython with a jar dependency

Tags: jar, jython

I installed jython 2.5.3 and I am trying to execute my script, which has a dependency with jsch.jar, using the command line. Then I tried something like this:

```
c:\myScriptLocation\> c:\jython2.5.3\jython.bat script.py
```

But it returns:

```
ImportError: No module named jcraft
```

**If I execute the jython script with Eclipse, it works**, because I can add the dependency in the System PYTHONPATH of the Jython Interpreter. **But I cannot use eclipse to execute the script, I have to do it with the command line.**

I tried to copy the jar file to the lib path of the jre jython is using, but doesn't work.

Any idea of the command I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do ...

```
c:\myScriptLocation\> c:\jython2.5.3\jython.bat -Dpython.path=\myJarLocation\jsch.jar script.py
```